# How to remove or delete single cron job using linux command?

Tags: linux, cron

I have created cron jobs by using "crontab -e" command. And they are working good . I tried crontab -r command which removes all cron job from server. 
These are my crons.

=> * 2 * * * root /usr/bin/php /home/user/test.php

=> * 3 * * * root /usr/bin/php /home/user/test2.php

=> * 4 * * * root /usr/bin/php /home/user/test3.php

How can I remove specific ones. Could you please help me for the solution ?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/408611/how-to-remove-or-delete-single-cron-job-using-linux-command

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways to perform this. 
1: By using crontab -e
2: Or if you have super user access then "/var/spool/cron/" path you will get the cron job files for each user like below.
cd /var/spool/cron/
 ll
total 4
-rw-------. 1 root root   0 Jan 13  2018 root
-rw-------. 1 root root 131 Jun 19 18:16 sam

A form that user, you can use the sed command to delete the single job.